# Flutter, test failing when running together but passing when running indivudally

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, dart-null-safety

I've been working on flutter unit testing on my API but I encountered a problem.

I've mocked an HTTP client to test all the POST, GET, DELETE, and PATCH requests. The problem is that when I run all my tests **together**, some tests on POST and PATCH requests fail (often after a test on a POST or PATCH request that passes) but when I run them **individually**, they pass.

The error I face is: `Bad state: Cannot call when within a stub response`

If anyone has encountered a similar problem and found a solution I would gladly take it :)

Thanks in advance for your time on my problem, I wish you all a good day!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?